# Are braces required for one-line functions?

Tags: java, c#, c++, c, coding-style

I know that curly braces are not required for one-line blocks, such as if statements, etc, but are they required for one line functions?

For example:

```
public int foo(int bar) 
    return bar;

public int foo(int bar) 
{
    return bar;
}
```

Are these both equally valid, or would the first example not be?

I am looking for answers relating to the C-family and similar languages (C, C++, C#, Java, etc).

Comment: Why not compile and see?

Comment: Ofcourse, it's syntax. We need braces

Comment: Yes, The method body comes inside the braces.

Comment: The answer is **YES**. For all the languages you've mentioned(At least C,C++,Java)

Comment: You could use #define to go around that.

Comment: In C# 6 you don't need them for expression body methods that take advantage of the lambda syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the time you read the answer you will probably know the answer to the question -**it's syntax, you can't avoid it**. But I will go one step further and explain why is it so?

Look when you are designing a compiler for any of the languages you have to deal with the `scope` and lifetime of a variable. Like
 in C

```
int p=2015;
int foo()
{ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~>
    int p=2014;          |
    printf("\n %d ",p);  |  This is the local scope 
    return p;            |
} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~>
```

> Output: 2014

Now as per the rule we always look for a variable in local scope then gradually towards the outer scope.

> So in a word you have to understand where new scope should be opened. That's what the '{' braces does. We can say that when compiler sees a '{' then obviously a scope begins and it ends when it encounter a '}'. This will help us store and manipulate the identifiers (well :-) it is symbol table throuh which we do this).

Now what happens if standard supports something that you have said--
:-( Problem ahead

```
int x=100;
int y=200;
int foo(int x)
 return x+y;-~~~~~~~~~~~> which x :-( the one that I have got as a parameter or the global one.

int main()
{
   int x=2;
   printf("%d\n",foo(x));
}
```

So this is the problem.Hope this helps.

If you run this with proper syntax

```
int foo(int x)
{
 return x+y;
}
```

the answer will be ..oh! you run it! the idea will be clear.

A part of C grammar (courtesy-Lysator)

```
function_definition
    : declaration_specifiers declarator declaration_list compound_statement
    | declaration_specifiers declarator compound_statement
    | declarator declaration_list compound_statement
    | declarator compound_statement
compound_statement
    : '{' '}'
    | '{' statement_list '}'
    | '{' declaration_list '}'
    | '{' declaration_list statement_list '}'
    ;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java you need Braces for the compiler to detect the lines after the method declaration as part of the method code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes braces are required for a function definition.  They are part of the language and not optional.

Answer (score 1):

For functions it is necessary however for different conditional loops, braces are not required for one line .